Convexity of function, Hessian
Im trying to understand convexity of a given function $$f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2+3x_1x_2+10x_1-11x_2+5.$$
My initial thought was to only take the second derivatives and check that $f_{xx} \geq 0$, and $f_{yy} \geq 0$, which they are which leads me to think that $f$ is convex. However, when computing the eigenvalues of the Hessian I get $\lambda_1=5, \lambda_2=-1$, which gives that the function is neither convex or concave, so clearly I have not understood the whole picture.
After some research I've understood that having both second derivatives greater or equal to 0 does only my convexity along the axis, but not globally.
So my question is - what is the difference between convexity along the axis and globally convex? I don't see the difference between those, and would appreciate if someone could make an visual example of what the difference is.

$f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are just two entries in the hessian of $f$. You are basically just computing the diagonal of the hessian but there are off diagonal entries (mixed derivatives like $f_{xy}$) as well. If the hessian is positive semidefinite then the function is convex.

If I have not done stupid mistakes in my calculations we have in this case the following:
$$5= f(0,0)= f\left (\frac 12 (-1,1) + \frac 12 (1,-1)\right ) > \frac 12 f(-1,1) +\frac 12 f(1,-1) = \frac 12 \cdot (-17) + \frac 12 \cdot 25 = 4.$$
This shows that $f$ is not convex. Now let me explain how I came up with this example:
The Hessian is given by $\begin{pmatrix} 2&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}$. It is an easy linear Algebra calculation to get $\lambda_1=5$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ as eigenvalues and find out that $(-1,1)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda_2=-1$. This means: along the line in the direction of $(-1,1)$ the second derivative is negative, hence restricted to that line, $f$ is not convex.
If you just check that $f_{xx}\ge 0$, then you have only shown that $t \mapsto f(x+t, y)$ is convex and checking $f_{yy}\ge 0$ implies only that $t \mapsto f(x,t+y)$ is convex, so you have only checked things for restrictions to single lines.
That is the reason why you have to check the whole Hessian for positive definiteness.
